# How to hande Mercurial Merge when editing same file

Tags: merge, mercurial

In `Rev 97` I started a branch named `tk-351`.

I edited a file named `thefile.php`

Meanwhile, I made another change to `thefile.php` in the `development branch` to fix a bug (`rev 99`).

When I `merged tk-351` (finished) to `default`, this movement `brought back the bug`, no conflict message or anything, just merged good.

So, in order to avoid this thing again (luckily it was a small change),

1) should I always pull from development before merging?
2) how can I avoid bringing ALL the changes from development (I just need to merge thefile.php, or files I have been working, to avoid bringing back bugs).

Comment: Merging does not bring back code, so it seems the situation is not like you describe it. OTOH, it is obviously possible to introduce bugs when merging, because it combines code which was never tested to work together properly.

Comment: Why you expected to have change, **which you have not done in merged branch-source**, in `default`??? **How**???